# javascript delete cookie works bizarre across browser

Tags: javascript, cookies

I'm trying to do a demo test on javascript cookie. Please find the code below which I wrote for testing.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type='text/javascript' >

function setcookie()
{   
    alert("check if cookie avail:" +document.cookie.split(';'));
    var dt=new Date();

    document.cookie='name=test';
    document.cookie='expires='+dt.toUTCString()+';'
    alert("now cookie val:" +document.cookie.split(';'));

    dt.setDate(dt.getDate()-1);
    document.cookie = "expires=" + dt.toUTCString() + ";"
    alert("after deletion cookie val:" + document.cookie.split(';'));
 }
</script>

</head>
<body>
    <input id='txt' onchange='setcookie()' />
</body>
</html>
```

The code will work as,

Initally, this will display the cookie which is present already in that browser, then I try to set a cookie as 'name=test' with 1day expire time. Using alert I can see the value set in that cookie. In the next line, I try to delete cookie by setting expire date to current date-1. If I use alert to print the cookie value, cookie is displayed with expire date as currentdate-1.

My questions is,

1. In Mozilla, If I refresh the browser and try to do the same step then the first alert displays the cookie value with expire time as currentdate-1. Why Im getting cookie value even if i delete at the last line of my script. However, once I close the browser the cookie value is empty. Why it is so?
2. In chrome,  If I run the same piece of code, neither of the cookie is set. Why Im not able to set cookie in chrome browsers.

Please tel me why such difference occuring across browsers.

Answer (score 1):

This is not setting the expiry

```
document.cookie='name=test';
document.cookie='expires='+dt.toUTCString()+';'
```

this is

```
document.cookie='name=test; expires='+dt.toUTCString()+';'
```

The best is to take well tested cookie code and use that

Try this one or use a jQuery plugin if you use jQuery

```
// cookie.js file
var daysToKeep = 14; // default cookie life...
var today      = new Date(); 
var expiryDate = new Date(today.getTime() + (daysToKeep * 86400000));


/* Cookie functions originally by Bill Dortsch */
function setCookie (name,value,expires,path,theDomain,secure) { 
   value = escape(value);
   var theCookie = name + "=" + value + 
   ((expires)    ? "; expires=" + expires.toGMTString() : "") + 
   ((path)       ? "; path="    + path   : "") + 
   ((theDomain)  ? "; domain="  + theDomain : "") + 
   ((secure)     ? "; secure"            : ""); 
   document.cookie = theCookie;
} 

function getCookie(Name) { 
   var search = Name + "=" 
   if (document.cookie.length > 0) { // if there are any cookies 
      var offset = document.cookie.indexOf(search) 
      if (offset != -1) { // if cookie exists 
         offset += search.length 
         // set index of beginning of value 
         var end = document.cookie.indexOf(";", offset) 
         // set index of end of cookie value 
         if (end == -1) end = document.cookie.length 
         return unescape(document.cookie.substring(offset, end)) 
      } 
   } 
} 
function delCookie(name,path,domain) {
   if (getCookie(name)) document.cookie = name + "=" +
      ((path)   ? ";path="   + path   : "") +
      ((domain) ? ";domain=" + domain : "") +
      ";expires=Thu, 01-Jan-70 00:00:01 GMT";
}
```

Comment: Sorry,I do not want any existing code. Here Im trying to learn javascript code on my own by doing samples. I just want to know the reason why my code is not working properly across browsers.